# вывести два json массива в одном ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

есть два разные массива по значениям и количеству содержания

php на который идет ajax запрос

```
 $result[] = $this->get_catById();
        $result[] =  $this->get_products();
        return  json_encode($result);
```

результат вывода (json) в консоле

```
0   […]
    0   {…}
        id_cat  695
        title_cat   iPad
        parent  691
    1   {…}
        id_cat  696
        title_cat   iPad 2
        parent  691
    2   {…}
        id_cat  697
        title_cat   iPad NEW (iPad 3)
        parent  691
    3   {…}
        id_cat  698
        title_cat   iPad 4
        parent  691

1   […]
    0   {…}
        id  13420
        title   Antenna 3G iPad NEW 3 (2pcs)
        price   6.8
        parent  697
        date    16-12-2019 00:00
    1   {…}
        id  10565
        title   Antenna iPad 2 bluetooth
        price   6.8
        parent  696
        date    12-12-2019 22:47
    2   {…}
        id  10566
        title   Antenna iPad 2 Wi-Fi
        price   6.2
        parent  696
        date    11-12-2019 13:46
    3   {…}
        id  13417
        title   Antenna iPad NEW 3 bluetooth
        price   4.8
        parent  697
        date    09-12-2019 21:42
    4   {…}
        id  13418
        title   Antenna iPad NEW 3 GPS
        price   4.8
        parent  697
        date    10-12-2019 10:50
```

ajax запрос

```
dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            var tr_str = '';
          var tr_str2 = '';

                var len = response.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var id = response[i].id;
                    var id_cat = response[i].id_cat;


                   tr_str2 +=
                       "<br />"+
                       "<span>" + id_cat + "</span>";
                tr_str2 += "</div>";

                    tr_str +=

                        "<h1>" +id+"</h1>" +

                        "</div>";

                    tr_str += "</div>";
                }

            $(".content").html(tr_str);
           $(".cat_content").html(tr_str2);
        }
```

в результате выводится undefined по два раза, в двух блоках, как вывести циклом результаты одного массива и второго?

Comment: надо создать внутри цикла `for(i)` еще один цикл `for(var j = 0; j<response[i].length;j++){` и результат выводить `console.log(response[i][j].id_cat);`, потому что массив многомерный

Comment: @Guest, TypeError: response[i][j] is undefined - выводит ошибку, если так сделать

Comment: а как выглядит строка, если в php сделать `print_r(json_encode($result))`?

Comment: @Guest, как выглядит строка, написано в примере, это нужно вывести циклом аяксом